# Why cart ID is null even though i can see the id from \Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart

Tags: cart, quote, shopping-cart, mini-cart, quoteitem

I am trying to get the cart value, i can get the quote id when i do x-debug.
[image]

if i try to get the id i get NULL
[image]

Anyone know why i get this